# Azure Front door back end target host name in the response header

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Is there a way to know the backend host getting hit when accessing frontdoor ?
Something like capturing the the backend target and recording it in the response header by front door
I have used the front door server variable host name in the rule set as the modify response header but it’s returning front door front end host
Ex: frontdoor.afd.net is returned instead of backend.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can add this into a response header in Front Door. You would need to add a header on your backend, something like `X-Server-Name` is often being used.

If you just want to find out after the fact which origin served a request, you can query that in the diagnostic logs of Azure Front Door (if you have enabled those and sent them for example into Azure Log Analytics). In the "FrontDoorAccessLog" entries you find a field for `OriginUrl_s`. You can correlate that using the `x-azure-ref` header value which Front Door injects.